# Latest Acumatica Update Introduced Error: "This source file has changed..." When Debugging Edited Source Files

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that since the latest update (Version 6.10.0755) a new critical bug may have been introduced. I'm asking here about it before reporting it just in case they introduced an option that would fix my issue.

My issue is that any time I edit a back end .cs file for a page, when I attach the program to the website instance and attempt to debug, I get the error message "This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the file used to build the application being debugged." It feels as though the Just-In-Time compiling feature has been "turned off." Can anyone give me any feedback if it was and how to fix it, or is anyone else experiencing this and should this be reported as a bug in the system?

Edit: I am using an instance which I updated from a previous 6.1 version (6.10.0269). The error is occurring on a graph extension of the SOOrder page. Fully customized pages seem to be fine. Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue in a new Acumatica web site?

If not can you provide a bit more information on your instance?

Like what kind of back end .cs file (new graph, new DAC, graph extension, DAC extension, ...)

and possibly add a screenshot of that error

Comment: Updated Question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the files are detected as changed but you should be able to re-attach to a fresh compiled instance with the following steps.

When attaching in visual studio, the Debug output window will list the compiled runtime code of the ASP application instance. It's in the file 'RuntimeCode_GUID.dll'

[image]

1. Stop IIS and the debugger, this will release the handle to the runtime code dll file
2. Delete the runtime code dll file
3. Restart IIS and open the web site in the browser, this will recompile the runtime code
4. Re-attach the debugger to the website

Comment: This is a common issue in ASP.Net if you edit a file while the debugger is still attached and other similar scenarios.

Comment: Also make sure you are debugging in the correct AppPool if there are multiple w3wp processes running.

Comment: I never had this issue before updating to the newest version of Acumatica. Do you know if they changed anything? Also to fix it, I just need to restart the instance. This only works until I make another change in SOOrder. Are the steps you put above for a more permanent fix?

Comment: No, the steps I listed make sure code is properly recompiled before you attach the debugger so they are the same version. I would be inclined to think your issue has more to do with your workflow and IIS than Acumatica latest version. Restarting the instance recompiles the RuntimeCode. Publishing the project should also recompile the RuntimeCode. If you just change code in visual studio without recompiling the RuntimeCode, then a code mismatch between source and the compiled RuntimeCode is the expected behavior.

Comment: You are correct and I understand that the mismatch is happening because the code is not being recompiled. That is what I'm trying to solve: Why is my code not automatically being recompiled? Before the update, it recompiled automatically anytime I made changes to the code (with or without attaching to the process). After the update, this all changed. I now have to manually recompile the code whether by restarting the IIS, publishing, or doing the steps you mentioned above. How can reactivate automatic recompile?

Comment: My experience with ASP is that you can't rely on ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation to automatically recompile the APP_CODE folder when a file is changed in there.

Comment: From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx By default, ASP.NET Web pages and code files are compiled dynamically when users first request a resource, such as an ASP.NET page (.aspx file), from a Web site. After pages and code files have been compiled the first time, the compiled resources are cached, so that subsequent requests to the same page are extremely efficient. It's not unusual to have IIS stuck on the cached copy until you recycle the AppPool, anything that prevents recycling the AppPool breaks automatic recompilation.

Comment: From: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx Any changes to a dynamically compiled file will automatically invalidate the file's cached compiled assembly and trigger recompilation of all affected resources. The next time a request to the code is made, ASP.NET recognizes that the code has changed and recompiles the affected resources of the Web application. After changing code, you might have to use a website functionality that calls runtime code in APP_RUNTIMECODE. Also using a single AppPool for your website might help in case another site is holding the cache.